# How to execute insert SQL through .bat file in Oracle?

Tags: sql, batch-file

I am doing a simple insert through .bat file. But It's not executing the second statement.

```
sqlplus scott/tiger


insert into dept values (60, 'Support', 'Redwood');
```

How can I run the second statement? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your columns are correct for insertion 
Here is what I would do.

> sqlplus scott/tiger @c:\yourSqlScript.sql
>       exit

Then in your "yourSqlScript.sql", you have

> insert into dept values (60, 'Support', 'Redwood');
>   exit

Answer (score 1):

To get it all to work from the .bat file, you need something like this:

```
@echo insert into dept values (60, 'Support', 'Redwood'); | sqlplus scott/tiger
```